# Download and next to upload data of an on line database

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have a problem with my project, I have my online database of altervista already filled and saved. But when I try to recover the data and pick them to enter into the listview charge only the first element of the table and the last two. Also it tries to load when the other row of the table here can not charge it. The table is like this: **ID**(int) autoincrement, title(text), description(longtext), body(longtext), source(text), date(text)
I use this php script to upload it:

```
<?php
        $host='localhost';
        $uname='root';   //Username per accedere nel database
        $pwd='';   //Password del database
        $db="my_notizieappandroid";   //Nome del database

                $select=$_REQUEST['id'];
        $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
        mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

        $r=mysql_query($select,$con);

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
        {
                $flag[]=$row;
        }

        print(json_encode($flag));
        mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

and now this is my java code. Costanti.java

```
public class Costanti {

    private static String UrlLink = "http://www.mysite.altervista.org/";
    private static String PHPShow = "visualizza.php";
    private static String TABLE_NOTIZIE = "news";
    private static String KAY_ID = "ID";
    private static String KAY_TITLE = "title";
    private static String KAY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static String KAY_BODY = "body";
    private static String KAY_SOURCE = "source";
    private static String KAY_DATE = "date";

    public static String getPHPShow() {
        return PHPShow;
    }

    public static String getKayDate() { return  KAY_DATE; }

    public static String getKaySource() {
        return KAY_SOURCE;
    }

    public static String getKayBody() {
        return KAY_BODY;
    }

    public static String getKayDescription() {
        return KAY_DESCRIPTION;
    }

    public static String getKayTitle() {
        return KAY_TITLE;
    }

    public static String getKayID() {
        return KAY_ID;
    }

    public static String getTableNotizie() {
        return TABLE_NOTIZIE;
    }

    public static String getUrlLink() {
        return UrlLink;
    }
}
```

CustomNewsAdapter.java:

```
public class CustomNewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {

    private List<News> Object;
    private static final int TYPE_RIGHT = 1;

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }
    public CustomNewsAdapter(Context C, List<News> Object){
        super(C, R.layout.news_row, Object);
        this.Object = Object;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int P, View convertV, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder vHolder;
        News person = Object.get(P);
        if (convertV == null) {
            convertV = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_row,null);
            TextView title = (TextView) convertV.findViewById(R.id.title_news);
            TextView description = (TextView) convertV.findViewById(R.id.description_news);
            vHolder = new ViewHolder(title, description);
            convertV.setTag(vHolder);
        } else {
            vHolder = (ViewHolder) convertV.getTag();
        }
        vHolder.getTitle().setText(person.getTitle());
        vHolder.getDescription().setText(person.getDescription());

        return convertV;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        public ViewHolder(TextView title, TextView description){
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public TextView getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public TextView getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    }
}
```

News.java

```
public class News {

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String source;
    private String body;
    private String date;
    private int ID;

    public News(int ID, String title, String description, String body, String source, String date) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.body = body;
        this.source = source;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() { return date; }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

NewsActivity.java:

```
public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent intent;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private ListView listView;
    private TextView textView;
    private List<News> newses;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view_news);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        newses = new ArrayList<News>();
        QuerySelect();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long offset) {

                News item = (News) newses.get(position);

                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewsSelectedActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("description", item.getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("body", item.getBody());
                intent.putExtra("source", item.getSource());
                intent.putExtra("date", item.getSource());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void QuerySelect() {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        String Select = "SELECT * FROM news";
        params.put("id", Select);
        client.post(Costanti.getUrlLink() + Costanti.getPHPShow(), params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                super.onFinish();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                String result = "";
                try {
                    result = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                if (!result.equals("null")) {
                    try {
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        parsingJsonArray(jsonArray);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Toast.makeText(NewsActivity.this, "Connessione Fallita!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void parsingJsonArray(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        try {
            for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                newses.add(new News(json_data.getInt(Costanti.getKayID()), json_data.getString(Costanti.getKayTitle()),
                        json_data.getString(Costanti.getKayDescription()), json_data.getString(Costanti.getKayBody()),
                        json_data.getString(Costanti.getKaySource()), json_data.getString(Costanti.getKayDate())));
            }

        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listView.setAdapter(new CustomNewsAdapter(NewsActivity.this, newses));
    }
}
```

NewsSelectedActivity.java

```
public class NewsSelectedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textViewTitle;
    TextView textViewDescription;
    TextView textViewBody;
    TextView textViewSource;
    TextView textViewDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_selected);
        textViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_news_selected);
        textViewDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_news_selected);
        textViewBody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.body_news_selected);
        textViewSource = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.source_news_selected);
        textViewDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_news_selected);


        String headline = "";
        String details = "";
        String text = "";
        String source = "";
        String date = "";

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (null != intent) {
            headline = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            details = intent.getStringExtra("description");
            text = intent.getStringExtra("body");
            source = intent.getStringExtra("source");
            date = intent.getStringExtra("date");
        }

        textViewTitle.setText(headline);
        textViewDescription.setText(details);
        textViewBody.setText(text);
        textViewSource.setText(source);
        textViewSource.setText(date);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

the listview is something like this: 
title: today we are ok
desription: null

title: null
description: null

So if i click an item
title: today we are ok
desctription: null
body: null
source: www.today.com
date: Date

Comment: Are you sure your database doesn't contain any `null` values or that you're using the correct column names ? Have you checked the response from the server to see if the error is in the way you parse and display the data or if it is a server side problem ?

Comment: I don't know if it's a server problem. But there are no null elements in the database and I use the same name column of the db in my code.

Comment: I can't see any errors in the code that you've posted, the only thing that doesn't look good is the hard-coded value returned by the `CustomNewsAdapter.getViewTypeCount()` method, you should override the `getCount()` method instead of this one and make it return the actual size `Object.size()`.

Comment: I've tried to change the method:
@Override                
public int getCount() {  
    return Object.size();
}
but the result is the same